# About oninput event to prevent letters input through MAC touch bar?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an input element which allows everything through MAC touch bar, I wonder any ideas to just allow digits? Maybe something like onInput events?

Comment: something like e.targer.valueAsNumber can be used. But e.preventDefault() seems not to work well in the handler.

Comment: onInput event not cancelable, we can set the value to be null.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the touch bar "guesses" the input by the `name` or `placeholder` of the input, not by the `type` (e.g. number, text, email) or from `inputmode` (tel, decimal,...) as you might expect from iOS